# event listener on click does not change height

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I am trying to build is that: I have two divs which inside have two divs. Initially the inner divs have 0 height. I have added event listeners to the external divs and when I click on a div the height of the internal becomes 50px. In addition I have added event listener to the internal divs and when I click I want the height of the internal dive to become 0 again, but it does not work. Every other css property like width or color did work. Below is the code.

```js
const mainContainer = document.querySelectorAll(".mainContainer");
const subMenu = document.querySelectorAll(".subMenu");

mainContainer.forEach(function(element, index) {
  element.addEventListener("click", function() {
    subMenu[index].style.height = "50px";
  })
})

subMenu.forEach(function(element, index) {
  element.addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.style.height = "10px";
  })
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 50%;
}

#mainContainer {
  border: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.subMenu {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0px;
  background-color: green;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: height 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="mainContainer">
    <p>this is the main box</p>
    <p>tha provides the main categories</p>
    <div class="subMenu">
      <p>This is the sub menu</p>
      <p>Lets build it</p>
      <p>Yes we do</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mainContainer">
    <p>this is the main box</p>
    <p>tha provides the main categories</p>
    <div class="subMenu">
      <p>This is the sub menu</p>
      <p>Lets build it</p>
      <p>Yes we do</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Replace `#mainContainer` with `.mainContainer` in css. This is a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have attached two event listeners to the element and both are fired at the same time, and the handler for the expansion overrides the handler for the collapsing:
[image]

The reason is whenever you are clicking on a child element, it passes the click event to the parent element also which changes the property again. you can use stopPropagation() in the child click function to stop the propagation of the click event. Check the updated code below.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation
(Credit to @Himanshu Budhiraja) for this great explanation

you didn't mention the expected behavior, I assumed based on the properties you set that you'd want it to expand and collapse.
It is not the best practice to control styling using inline styling. it is better to add or remove class, such as here, I added the class ".expanded", and I used classList for toggling it on and off

```js
const mainContainer = document.querySelectorAll(".mainContainer");
const subMenu = document.querySelectorAll(".subMenu");

mainContainer.forEach(function(element, index) {
  element.addEventListener("click", function() {
    subMenu[index].classList.toggle("expanded");
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 50%;
}

#mainContainer {
  border: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.subMenu {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0px;
  background-color: green;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: height 0.5s;
}

.expanded {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="mainContainer">
    <p>this is the main box</p>
    <p>tha provides the main categories</p>
    <div class="subMenu">
      <p>This is the sub menu</p>
      <p>Lets build it</p>
      <p>Yes we do</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mainContainer">
    <p>this is the main box</p>
    <p>tha provides the main categories</p>
    <div class="subMenu">
      <p>This is the sub menu</p>
      <p>Lets build it</p>
      <p>Yes we do</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like, you are not able to collapse it. The reason is whenever you are clicking on a child element, it passes the click event to the parent element also which changes the property again. you can use stopPropagation() in the child click function to stop the propagation of the click event. Check the updated code below.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

One more thing, mainContainer and subMenu are classes (html) but in your CSS code, you are using them as ids.

```js
const mainContainer = document.querySelectorAll(".mainContainer");
const subMenu = document.querySelectorAll(".subMenu");

mainContainer.forEach(function(element, index) {
  element.addEventListener("click", function() {
    subMenu[index].style.height = "50px";
  })
})

subMenu.forEach(function(element, index) {
  element.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  this.style.height = "10px";
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trying to use something already done such as [multi-level menu](https://codepen.io/geo2arc/pen/pJvEaK). Here are [more examples](https://onaircode.com/javascript-accordion-menu/).
In addition to that try using `max-width` to animate and set the height to auto.

```js
const mainContainer = document.querySelectorAll(".mainContainer");
const subMenu = document.querySelectorAll(".subMenu");

mainContainer.forEach( function(element, index) {
  element.addEventListener("click", function() {
    subMenu[index].style.maxHeight = "100px";
  })
})

subMenu.forEach( function(element, index) {
  element.addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.style.maxHeight = "100px";
  })
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#container {
 border: 1px solid red; 
  width: 50%;
}

#mainContainer {
  border: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.subMenu {

  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-height:0;
  background-color: green;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: max-height 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="mainContainer">
    <p>this is the main box</p>
      <p>tha provides the main categories</p>
      <div class="subMenu">
        <p>This is the sub menu</p>
        <p>Lets build it</p>
        <p>Yes we do</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mainContainer">
      <p>this is the main box</p>
      <p>tha provides the main categories</p>
      <div class="subMenu">
        <p>This is the sub menu</p>
        <p>Lets build it</p>
        <p>Yes we do</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The are two real keys here:

Use `max-height` instead of `height` to allow the content's `height` to calculate to `auto` and then `max-height` acts as a potential override to `height`.

In the sub-menus, you must stop the `click` event from bubbling up because if it does, it will reach the main menu, where that `click` event will trigger and cause conflicts.

You should also not be using relative or absolute positioning to make this work.

See other comments inline below:

```js
const mainContainer = document.querySelectorAll(".mainContainer");
const subMenu = document.querySelectorAll(".subMenu");

mainContainer.forEach( function(element) {
  element.addEventListener("click", function() {
    // Simpler to find the child element within the parent
    // than to rely on idexes. Also, easier to work with 
    // CSS classes than inline styles.
    this.querySelector(".subMenu").classList.toggle("open");
  })
})

subMenu.forEach( function(element) {
  element.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    // Since a sub-menu is a descendent of the mainContainer,
    // you have to stop the click event from bubbling up to the
    // ancestor otherwise it's click event will also trigger.
    event.stopPropagation();
    
    // If someone clicks, it will be on a <p> withing
    // the sub menu, so you need to set the style on
    // the closest ancestor .submenu, not this.
    this.classList.toggle("open");
  })
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#container {
 border: 1px solid red; 
 width: 50%;
}

.mainContainer {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 100%;
}

.subMenu {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0px;
  background-color: green;
  transition: max-height 0.5s;
}

.open { max-height:50px; }
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="mainContainer">
      <p>this is the main box</p>
      <p>tha provides the main categories</p>
      <div class="subMenu">
        <p>This is the sub menu 1</p>
        <p>Lets build it</p>
        <p>Yes we do</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mainContainer">
      <p>this is the main box</p>
      <p>tha provides the main categories</p>
      <div class="subMenu">
        <p>This is the sub menu 2</p>
        <p>Lets build it</p>
        <p>Yes we do</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```